# Very difficult contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have to compute this integral and I don't have any idea how to get further on:

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\mid z \mid = 1} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7}dz$$

I tried Rouché to maybe exclude some singularities from $B(0,1)=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \, |z| <1\}$ and then apply the residue theorem with no success.
Thanks for help !

My Rouché try:
$f(z) := 23z^{99}-2z^{81}+z^4-7 ~~~~~~g(z) := 23 z^{99}$
$ \Rightarrow \forall \,z$ with $ |z| = 1 :~~|f(z)-g(z)|=|-2z^{81}+z^4-7| \leq 2+1+7 = 10 <23=|g(z)| \leq |g(z)|+|f(z)| $
$ \Rightarrow$ All zeroes of $f$ lie in $B(0,1)$

Comment: For this one it's best to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Residue_at_infinity which indeed is what @Daniel Fischer suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The denominator has no zeros in $\{z:\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 1\}$, so we can use Cauchy's integral theorem to shift the contour to a large circle,

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99} -2z^{81} + z^4 -7}\,dz = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99} -2z^{81} + z^4 -7}\,dz$$

for any $R \geqslant 1$. We can easily compute the limit

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99} -2z^{81} + z^4 -7}\,dz$$

with the parametrisation $z = R e^{i\varphi}$.

Comment: I see. We get that $lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \frac{6(R e^{i\varphi})^{98}}{23(R e^{i\varphi})^{99} -2(R e^{i\varphi})^{81} + (R e^{i\varphi})^4 -7} = 0$  Am I right ?

Comment: Don't forget that $dz = iRe^{i\varphi}\, d\varphi$, the limit is not $0$.

Comment: $\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{6z^{98}}{23z^{99} -2z^{81} + z^4 -7}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{6(R e^{i \varphi})^{98} i R e^{i \varphi}}{23(R e^{i \varphi})^{99} -2(R e^{i \varphi})^{81} + (R e^{i \varphi})^4 -7}\,d\varphi = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{6}{23}d\varphi ~~~~~?$

Comment: You lost a factor of $i$, the right hand side is $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{6}{23}\,d\varphi.$$ Otherwise, it's right.

Comment: OK and finally I get: $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}...= \frac{6}{23}~~ ?$

Comment: Yes, that's the result.

Comment: One last question which I not sure about: What argument can we invoke to interchange limit and integral ? The uniform convergence of the fraction ?

Comment: Ah, the residue at infinity. So it would also be possible to substitute $u=1/z$ and for the resulting integral consider the residue at zero.

Comment: @ThomasProduit Yes, it's the uniform convergence on $[0,2\pi]$ that allows the interchange.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your quick responses !

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not correct.

We can start by using the residue theorem to evaluate the given complex contour integral. To do so, we need to identify the poles of the integrand within the given contour.

The integrand has poles at z = 0, z = -1, z = -1/3, and z = 1/3. However, only the pole at z = 0 lies inside the given contour, which has radius 16.

To compute the residue at z = 0, we can use the fact that for a pole of order m, the residue is given by the coefficient of the (m-1)th term in the Laurent series expansion of the integrand around the pole.

The pole at z = 0 has order 4, so we can expand the integrand in a Laurent series around z = 0. We get:

z^(-4)(z^98-23z^9+9z^-2+2z^-18+z^-4)-7/z^4

= z^(-8) (z^102 - 23z^13 + 9 + 2z^-14 - 7z^-8)

The coefficient of the (4-1) = 3rd term in the Laurent series expansion is -7/6. Therefore, the residue at z = 0 is -7/6.

By the residue theorem, the value of the integral is 2πi times the residue at z = 0. Thus, we have:

12πi ∫ |z|=16 z^98-23z^9+9z^-2+2z^-18+z^-4-7dz = 2πi (-7/6) = -7πi/3.

Therefore, the value of the given contour integral is -7πi/3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).